# group elements in list by pairwise criterion in python

Tags: python, list, iterator

I am implementing a local optimization that fuses objects together. In the simplest form, given a list:

`[0, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 9, 0, 3, 5]`

I would like to group into:

`[[0, 3], 5, 8, 1, 2, 9, [0, 3], 5]`

which is based on a provided criterion:

```
def is_group(a, b):
    return a == 0 and b == 3
```

My current solution seems a bit convoluted, and am looking for most pythonic approach:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    for (a, b) in zip(iterable, iterable[1:]):
        yield (a, b)
    yield (iterable[-1], None)  # handle edge case

def fuse(ops):
    ops_new = []
    skip_next = False
    for (a, b) in pairwise(ops):
        if is_group(a, b):
            ops_new.append([a, b])
            skip_next = True
        elif skip_next:
            skip_next = False
        elif:
            ops_new.append(a)
```

I've looked at `groupby`, which is the closest but aren't quite sure how to make it work since here the criterion depends on pairwise arguments.

Edit: Another way to ask the question is I am basically trying to do pattern search and replace with lists (e.g. `regex` for lists).

Comment: What's the edge-case you are handling in `pairwise`? IOW, why do you need to consider the last element against `None`?

Comment: Thanks for the question. If I don't include that handling, then pairwise just returns `(0, 3), (3, 5), (5, 8), ..., (3, 5)`. My fuse operation never appends `b`, so my result would always be missing the last element.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense. Well, then in that case the only thing I would change would be `from itertools import zip_longest, islice` Then simply `zip_longest(x, islice(x, 1, None))` instead of your `pairwise`

Answer (score 1):

Custom **`isolate_group`** function:

```
def isolate_group(pair, l):
    result = []
    idx_skip = -1

    for i in range(len(l)):
        if i == idx_skip:
            continue
        if l[i:i+2] == pair:
            result.append(l[i:i+2])
            idx_skip = i+1
        else:
            result.append(l[i])

    return result
```

Test 1:

```
print(isolate_group([0,3], [0, 3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 9, 0, 3, 5]))
```

The output:

```
[[0, 3], 5, 8, 1, 2, 9, [0, 3], 5]
```

---

Test 2:

```
print(isolate_group([0,3], [0, 3, 5, 8, 0, 3, 9, 5, 0, 3]))
```

The output:

```
[[0, 3], 5, 8, [0, 3], 9, 5, [0, 3]]
```